# How to insert real File object to function in React unit tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a function that accepts `File` object as input parameter. Normally function gets it from `form` element, where user selects file.

Function converts input `File` to `Image`, manipulating it and then returns a blob. Conversion is done with `image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);`, where `file` is input `File` object.

But how can I test that function with real files with jest? I need to read real image from local filesystem and pass it to that function. Any advice how to do that?

Comment: You can read file contents with Node fs.readFileSync and put it into a mock.

Comment: Thats promising, but I need `File` object. Tried to read file contents to `fileContents` and create `new File([fileContents], 'test.jpg', { type: 'image/jpeg' });` but all I get is empty `File {}`. Contents reading works, but how can I convert it to working `File` object?

Comment: What are exactly your expectations from this object? The question doesn't contain information. Jest uses fake DOM that isn't expected to work like real browser and will fail at many things. If you use it with FileReader, mock it in the first place.

Comment: Added some info about the function.

Comment: createObjectURL is not available in fake DOM. See https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1721 . Mock it.

Comment: How can I mock it? I can't touch the function itself, I just have to test it. But it seems impossible if fake dom can't run it.

Comment: Fake DOM is written by human beings. You need to extend the implementation to suit your needs. `URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn()` and then mock it according to your expectations. Spy or mock `global.File` if you need to make sure it was provided with correct arguments. That's how it's done in Jest. If you want to test how it works in real life, do tests in real browser.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems that I have much to learn about testing.